# Re-ordering columns in a csv but with Dictionaries broken

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a code that is braking because I am trying to reorganize columns but also ignoring other columns on the output csv file.

Input csv file:

```
book1.csv
A,B,C,D,E,F
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,F1
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,F1
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,F1
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,
```

My code:

```
import csv

order_of_headers_should_be = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B']
dictionary = {'A':'X1','B':'Y1','C':'U1','D':'T1','E':'K1'}
new_headers = [dictionary[old_header] for old_header in order_of_headers_should_be]

with open('Book1.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    # output dict needs a list for new column ordering
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = new_headers)
    # reorder the header first
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        new_row = {dictionary[old_header]: row[old_header] for old_header in row}
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

my current output is only the headers (but they are in the correct order):

```
X1,U1,T1,K1,Y1
```

Getting an KeyError: 'F'
But I need it to also output so it will look like this:

```
reordered.csv
X1,U1,T1,K1,Y1
a1,c1,d1,e1,b1
a1,c1,d1,e1,b1
a1,c1,d1,e1,b1
a1,c1,d1,e1,b1
a1,c1,d1,e1,b1
```

Comment: You should be getting a `KeyError` for the header `F` that doesn't exist in `dictionary`.

Comment: Yes, I am. I am trying to make it where it would just ignore the F for now if thats possible

Answer (score 2):

When `old_header` is `F` you'll get a `KeyError`, so the `for row` loop will stop and you won't get any data rows in the output file.

Add a check for this to ther dictionary comprehension.

```
new_row = {dictionary[old_header]: value for old_header, value in row.items() if old_header in dictionary}
```

You could also loop through `dictionary` instead of `row`.

```
new_row = {new_header: row[old_header] for old_header, new_header in dictionary}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way using pandas to do the heavy lifting.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV file into DataFrame df
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')

# delete F column
df = df.drop('F', axis=1)

# rename columns
df.columns = ['X1', 'Y1', 'U1', 'T1', 'K1']

# write to file in desired order
df.to_csv('book_out.csv', index=False,
          columns=['X1', 'U1', 'T1', 'K1', 'Y1'])
```